# How can I intercept the output stream and check?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How can I intercept the output stream and check?

Like I enter a command to delete folders, for example like this:
`rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/*`

And sometimes if someone walks the site, I can get an error that even has not cleaned up

`rm: cannot remove 'pub/static/frontend/Test/testtheme': Directory not empty`

How to make the correct check-in a sh script like if you get an error, then repeat the cleaning until there is no message, then continue executing the script

```
echo 'something doing'

error = ""
while read line
do
    rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/*
    if [[ error == something ]]
    then
        rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/*
    fi
done

echo 'continue something doing'
```

Comment: What would be the point?  Classic race condition.  If your script "works", then the directories don't exist; but someone might create a file 2 ms after you're done scraping. Had the file been created 4 ms earlier, you would have deleted them.  Continuously checking and then moving on when you're satisfied solves nothing.  Your follow-on process must be able to deal with any files that exist, since they may appear immediately after you're done checking.

Comment: If you intend to remove the directory, you should disable whatever code tries to add more files to the directory first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
while :; do
    rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/*
    [[ $? == 0 ]] && break
; done
```

Comment: Seems cleaner to write `while ! rm -rf ...; do sleep 1; done`